# Is it possible to post from an external RoR site to Sitecore

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sitecore

Looking into possibly doing an integration with a blog that is powered by Sitecore.  Is there anyway to use data from our site (RoR) to create a post on an external Sitecore blog?  I guess something analogous to the Wordpress XML-RPC api or the Tumblr Restful API.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into using the [Sitecore Item Web API](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Products/Sitecore%20Item%20Web%20API/SitecoreItemWebApi10.aspx) module, it's officially support by Sitecore and will give you CRUD access to Sitecore items.

You can restrict access to operations using standard Sitecore Security and [passing in the user credentials when building the request](http://sitecorecreative.wordpress.com/2013/03/08/sitecore-item-web-api-client-create/). Additionally, like all things Sitecore, you can extend the API with pipeline processors to add anything else you require.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Visual Sitecore Service to create new items from your RoR website.
The Visual Sitecore Service is a webservice that is standard installed in Sitecore which enables you to read/write/create to and from Sitecore.

See [this link](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/65/Sitecore_Web_Service_SC65_A4.pdf) for more information about the Visual Sitecore Service webservice.

You could also create your own webservice in Sitecore, that is what I mostly prefer to gain full control of the functionalities of the webservice.

Another option could be to read the data (periodically or realtime) from a JSON (or other) service from your RoR website and save it in Sitecore or XML format in file or custom database table. Whatever you prefer and fits your requirements.

Comment: Thanks Martijn!  Gonna leave this open for another day just in case, but this seems like a totally viable solution.

Comment: Don't forget we also have the [Sitecore Web Item API](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sdn5/modules/sitecore%20item%20web%20api/sitecore_item_web_api_developer_guide_sc65-66-usletter.pdf) available to us

Comment: Even better!  Thanks @jammykam.  If you want to move this to a separate answer, I'll mark it as accepted.